# Trouble implementing custom haptics(with varying sharpness and intensity) on iPhone 7 Plus

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, haptic-feedback

I recently came across Google Calendar iOS app, and it provides a crisp-yet-very-light haptic feedback when dragging or creating events. I'm trying to implement the same.

I figured out that the `UIImpactFeedbackGenerator`'s `.light` impact is still too strong for my requirement.

After a bit of digging, I came across `CHHapticEngine` from the 'Core Haptics' library which supports custom haptics when provided with 'sharpness' and 'intensity' parameters. But it seems like this ***`CHHapticEngine` does not work on an iPhone 7 Plus and Google has somehow pulled this off.***

`CHHapticEngine` does not work?

1) `CHHapticEngine.capabilitiesForHardware().supportsHaptics` returns `false`

2) When I try to use it without the check, it returns:

> (com.apple.CoreHaptics error -4809.)

So, is there another way to generate custom haptics(with varying sharpness and intensity levels) that works universally on all iOS devices that have Taptic Engine? TYIA!

Comment: did you find anything? i have a problem that IPhones 7 should support CHHapticEngine (it has taptic engine in it), but it doesn't for some reason

Comment: I ended up achieving almost the same output with `UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .rigid)` with an intensity of `0.7` (If a similar haptic output is what you're after, compared to the means of achieving it, you can explore this route)

Comment: @ nt4f04und Did you find a solution?